# Can't compile Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I'm trying to compile Qt Creator source code and got the following error message:

```
fatal error: QtCore/private/qwineventnotifier_p.h : No such file or directory.
```

I'm on Win XP SP3 using QtSDK version 1.1.3, MinGW (g++ 4.5.2). In the QtCore folder of the QtSDK includes there is no any folder named private, and searching for qwineventnotifier_p.h yielded nothing. What can i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Edit:]

Apparently there's an issue with this recently:

https://bugreports.qt-project.org//browse/QTCREATORBUG-3701

https://bugreports.qt-project.org//browse/QTBUG-17218

You my try getting the file from somewhere, e.g.:

http://cep.xor.aps.anl.gov/software/qt4-x11-4.2.2-browser/df/d69/src_2corelib_2kernel_2qwineventnotifier__p_8h-source.html

But I can't tell if this will be enough or if Qt Creator will rely on the actual sources for that header file.

Comment: I'm using Qt 4.7.4. Will it work if i have a copy of the header file? (i not sure about the compiled library for it).